# Load a page through a webserver, then to client?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube, proxy

I would like to have my server load pages and then server that page to the client.

I have a partnered youtube account and I have allowed only those from certain countries to view my videos. But, I also embed the clips to my personal webpage.

So is it possible for my webserver to make the requests to youtube? Thus allowing any geo-local to watch my videos - as long as they are watching through my website?  (This is assuming my webserver is in the UK or USA or other 'allowed countries' to watch my videos). I'm assuming if this is possible I'd have to set up a proxy system on my side or something.

I appreciate any insight and resources.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's called a proxy. You probably won't want to do it. Serving video is a HUGE bandwidth hit, and you'll be getting hit TWICE: once to download from youtube, and once to upload to your user.

Comment: I can't see the benefit to locking out certain countries on YouTube's site, but not when it's embedded on your webpage. Is this is a money-making thing?

Comment: What you are proposing is against the [Youtube TOS](http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be over-complicating this a little... If your videos are hosted on YouTube, you can get code to embed it onto your page. I don't know if that will get around your security settings however, but scraping the page wouldn't achieve that either since it would still be streamed from YouTube.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480061

Re-read your question, and it seems you have figured that part out. I don't think you can pull the video the way you are asking though. You would still need to stream the video from YouTube.